# How to print a pdf with editable fields inside another pdf, .NET?

Tags: c#, .net-core, pdf-generation, pdf-reader

I have the code that I use to add(print) a pdf document inside another with other valuable infos that I need, recently I realized that this won't work with a pdf that has editable fields, the pdf will print but not the filled fields, the first idea that came to my mind was to convert each pdf page to image then print the image to the pdf, I started searching on this but still I couldn't make this work yet, do you guys have any ideas on how i could make this work?

This is some part of my code..

```
            public static void AttachPdfDocument(DruckKontext<DruckDatenOhneErgebnis> druckKontext, string pdfBaseString, string docName,
        Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> fieldNamesAndValues)
    {
        try
        {

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Convert.FromBase64String(pdfBaseString));
            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
            PdfWriter writer = druckKontext.Writer;
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
            for (int p = 1; p <= reader.NumberOfPages; p++)
            {

                PdfImportedPage page = canvas.PdfWriter.GetImportedPage(reader, p);
                canvas.AddTemplate(page, (PageSize.A4.Width / page.Width) * 0.7, 0, 0, (PageSize.A4.Height / page.Height) * 0.7, 85, BeratungsdokuStyle.DruckhöheMin + 20);
                if (p < reader.NumberOfPages)
                {
                    druckKontext.NewPageBeratungsdokumentation();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[Printed pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2p4j.png)

[PDF with editable fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tGSZ.png)

Comment: View your task as combining two pdfs, the one with the form and the one with the Beratungsdokumentation. Thus, first create the latter one as a separate pdf using a `Document` / `PdfWriter` pair, and then merge your two pdfs using `Document` / `PdfCopy` and two `PdfReaders`.

Comment: See, as I told in the description and the photos I already managed to put the pdf inside the other, the problem  stands that the editable fields are going blank after printing

Comment: *"as I told in the description... the problem stands that the editable fields are going blank after printing"* - and that's why I proposed that you do it differently. Your approach drops fields altogether. Using `PdfCopy` does not drop them.